# Full width element: How to make an absolute positioned element to be full width within a grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

- I have an article which is within a grid.
- The Article body spans 6 columns
- I need one of the items within the article body to go full width (beyond the 6 columns container)
- The element i am trying make full width is a video / iframe which needs to keep an aspect ratio of 16:9
- The video / iframe is absolutely positioned

Here is the code pen so far.

https://codepen.io/miteshsevani/pen/xxEGQdX

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1536px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  padding-left: 48px;
  padding-right: 48px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 -8px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.article__layout {
  grid-column: 2/9;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.video-player.u-align--full-width {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.u-align__wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-column: 1/7;
  align-items: center;
  /* display: flex; */
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.video-player__source.u-align__container {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="article__layout">
      <div>
        <div class="article-body-text">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis
            imperdiet.</p>

          <!-- VIDEO BLOCK START -->

          <div>
            <div class="alignBodyVideoPlayer">
              <div clas="video-player u-align--full-width">
                <div class="u-align__wrapper">
                  <iframe class="video-player__source u-align__container" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c">
                </iframe>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- VIDEO BLOCK END -->


          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis
            imperdiet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get it to go full width / edge to edge?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to remove your class `grid` in your design and add `width:100%` to the class `.u-align__wrapper` from what I've observed `.u-align__wrapper` class contains `width:100vw`.

Here's the full preview.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1536px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  padding-left: 48px;
  padding-right: 48px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 -8px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.article__layout {
  grid-column: 2/9;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.video-player.u-align--full-width {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 16px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7,1fr);
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.u-align__wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    grid-column: 1/7;
    align-items: center;
    /* display: flex; */
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.video-player__source.u-align__container {
  left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="">
    <div class="article__layout">
      <div>
        <div class="article-body-text">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet.</p>
          
<!-- VIDEO BLOCK START -->
          
        <div>
          <div class="alignBodyVideoPlayer">
            <div clas="video-player u-align--full-width">
              <div class="u-align__wrapper">
                <iframe class="video-player__source u-align__container" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c">
                </iframe>
               </div>                      
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
          
<!-- VIDEO BLOCK END -->
          
          
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet.</p>           
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i can't get rid of the grid as a lot of other things on the page are dependent on it.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I'm able to understand your problem, if you remove `position: relative;` style from your `.u-align__wrapper` class and add `position: relative;` to your parent div, i.e `.container` class, then the video will be of full width and height.